# Not catching WIN32 cim exception

Tags: powershell, exception, dns

I am having an issue with the following `FullyQualifiedErrorId: WIN32 9741`.

I am doing the following and for some reason this is not catching the error. I can't seem to find much detail online and was wondering if anyone has any ideas.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";

try
{
   Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName testerror -Name testst
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
}
```

The unhandled exception only occurs if the `-ZoneName` evaluates to `true` and `-Name` evaluates to `false`. If `-ZoneName` is `false` then the exception gets caught.

Comment: Just use `catch {..}` without the `[Exception]`

Comment: Tried that and same issues persists

Comment: Tried that and the exception got cought in both ways: `Failed to get was record in MyZone zone on dc01 server.` for not existing record inside existing Zone, and `The zone blubb was not found on server dc01.`for not existing Zone.

Comment: The second one only catches for me

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit late to the party, but the ones who still struggle with this issue, I've found a solution ([Credit to here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/16/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/)):

```
try{
    Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "your.domain.com" -Name $NewDNSRecordResourceName -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException]{
        $error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName
        Write-Host "DNS record does not exist"
}
catch{
#Do something for the rest of the exceptions
}
```

The key is the argument "-ErrorAction Stop" and to quote the source:

> But, why did the [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException
>   ] message appear? Because the ErrorAction Preference is set to Continue: